# ExecutionFailure "unknown identifier" in ORDER BY when using UNION

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been puzzled by the error the following cypher query returns:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r_ptq]->(tq:Ticket)
WHERE tq.name IN ["music", "sports", "movie"]
RETURN distinct(p1) AS person, count(r_ptq) AS score, collect(tq.name) AS tickets
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10

UNION

MATCH (t:Ticket)<-[r_ttq]-(tq:Ticket)
WHERE tq.name IN ["music", "sports", "movie"]
WITH distinct(t), sum(r_ttq.weight) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 50
MATCH (t)<--(p:Person)
RETURN distinct(p) AS person, sum(weight) AS score, collect(t.name) AS tickets
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

This will always return

```
Unknown identifier `score`.
```

apparently the identifier "score" in the `ORDER BY` instruction isn't recognized when combining the queries with the UNION. If I run the two queries separately (above and below `UNION`, this works perfectly fine. Also if I remove the `ORDER BY` instruction, it will work with the UNION but of course this will change the behavior.

Any pointers on how to resolve this are greatly appreciated.

I adjusted above example to work on the graph on [console.neo4j.org](http://console.neo4j.org)

```
MATCH (p1:Crew)-[r_ptq]->(tq:Crew)
WHERE tq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
RETURN distinct(p1) AS person, count(r_ptq) AS score, collect(tq.name) AS tickets
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
UNION
MATCH (t:Crew)<-[r_ttq]-(tq:Crew)
WHERE tq.name IN ["Neo", "Morpheus"]
WITH distinct(t), count(r_ttq) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
LIMIT 50
MATCH (t)<--(p:Crew)
RETURN distinct(p) AS person, sum(weight) AS score, collect(t.name) AS tickets
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

and it returns
`Error: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Unknown identifier 'weight'.`

running the queries sperately without the UNION works fine.

Comment: This query does execute without a problem. Try it out in console.neo4j.org

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher query is syntactically correct and works in the Neo4j browser. The console at console.neo4j.org seems to have some JavaScript RegEx validation that has a bug when tracking identifiers in UNION with WITH. We'll look into this bug and fix it in the console.

For now, please use the Neo4j 2.0 browser by download Neo4j at http://www.neo4j.org/download.